# .NET framework is copied to 'compiler/CLR' and 'GAC?

Tags: .net, assemblies, gac

The book of CLR via C# has this line at page 76.

> When you install the .NET Framework,
>   tow copies of Microsoft's assembly
>   files are actuall installed. One set
>   is installed into the compiler/CLR
>   directory, and another set is
>   installed into GAC subdirectory

I could find the GAC at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly`, but I couldn't find the compiler/CLR thing.

- What's the physical directory name of compiler/CLR? I mean, where is it?
- Why there are two GAC in assembly directory? I find GAC_32 and GAC_MSIL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For framework 2.0 32 bit : C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
For framework 2.0 64 bit : C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727

GAC_MSIL is for assemblies in MSIL format, GAC_32 is for '[ngen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28VS.80%29.aspx)'ed native assemblies in the x86 format. On a 64 bit machine you will also see GAC_64 folder which stores the AMD64 native images of assemblies.

Comment: What is the name of the GAC folder for IA64 native assemblies?